# How to modify the same attribute of multiple lists with exact schemas in Sharepoint online through coding or ms flow

Tags: powershell, microsoft-flow, c-sharp, python

I have several lists with the same exact schemas in SharePoint Online. How can I do the following?

1- How to add/remove a column to/from all of them?

2- How to add/remove an option to a choice/multichoice column?

I think there should be a way to accomplish this in C#/Python or through Powershell. I prefer coding as it makes life much easier and faster. MS flow is fine.

Please let me know if it would be better to break this question into two seprate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer PowerShell for tasks like these.

**Install PnP PowerShell module:**

```
Install-Module PnP.PowerShell -force -Scope CurrentUser
```

If you are behind proxy, you may need to install the msi package from the below link:
https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/releases/tag/3.9.1905.3

**Connect to a SharePoint Site**

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://YOUR_TENANT.sharepoint.com -UseWebLogin
```

**Add a new field to a list using Add-PnPField**

```
Add-PnPField -List "Demo list" -DisplayName "Location" -InternalName "SPSLocation" -Type Choice -AddToDefaultView -Choices "Stockholm","Helsinki","Oslo"
```

**Updating the list of choices is a little trickier. It is [described by Tse Kit Yam tsekityam:](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1846)**

> We can modify the options of a choice field by modifying the schema
> xml of the field
>
> Let say the field Fruit has 2 options, Apple and Orange and we want to
> add Banana to the list
>
> First we get the schema xml of the field

```
$field = Get-PnPField -List 20559154-6a7e-4e67-b10b-a12bbc943152 -Identity Fruit
[xml]$schemaXml = $field.SchemaXml
```

> The schema xml of the field should looks like this

```
<Field DisplayName="Fruit" FillInChoice="FALSE" Format="Dropdown" Title="Fruit" Type="Choice" ID="{98354d16-9929-4a1f-a97a-347694aaadad}" SourceID="{20559154-6a7e-4e67-b10b-a12bbc943152}" StaticName="Fruit" Name="Fruit" ColName="nvarchar4" RowOrdinal="0">
    <CHOICES>
        <CHOICE>Apple</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Orange</CHOICE>
    </CHOICES>
</Field>
```

> Then we may add the new choice, Banana, to the schema

```
$banana = $schemaXml.CreateElement("CHOICE")
$banana.InnerText = "Banana"
$schemaXml.Field.CHOICES.AppendChild($banana)
```

> Finally we can update the schema xml of the field

```
Set-PnPField -List 20559154-6a7e-4e67-b10b-a12bbc943152 -Identity Fruit -Values @{SchemaXml=$schemaXml.OuterXml}
```

> Now the field should have 3 options Apple, Orange and Banana in the list

So, the full code after following the above steps is:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites -UseWebLogin 
Add-PnPField -List "Test_List" -DisplayName "LocationTest" -InternalName "LT_innrname" -Type Choice -AddToDefaultView -Choices "Auckland","Wlg","Queenstown"
$field = Get-PnPField -List 72e2073a-listid-b9abbc2 -Identity LT_innrname
[xml]$schemaXml = $field.SchemaXml
$new_city = $schemaXml.CreateElement("CHOICE")
$new_city.InnerText = "New City"
$schemaXml.Field.CHOICES.AppendChild($new_city)
Set-PnPField -List 72e2073a-listid-b9abbc2 -Identity LT_innrname -Values @{SchemaXml=$schemaXml.OuterXml}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]